# Dúvidas Assembly mips

Tags: assembly, mips

Alguém poderia me explicar como utilizar And, Andi, Or, Ori, Nor em Assembly mips? Pois gostaria de fazer algo desse tipo:

```
se (num1 > 0) e (num2 > 0) entao
    se (num1 <= 10) e (num2 <= 10) entao
       cont <- num1 + num2
       se (cont = resultado) entao
          escreval ("Parabéns você acertou!")
       seNao
          escreval ("Você errou!")
          escreva ("O resultado é: ")
          escreva (cont)
       fimSe
    seNao
       EscrevaL(" STATUS: ALGO INCOMUM. ")
       EscrevaL(" Você digitou os dados corretos? ")
    fimSe
 seNao
    EscrevaL(" STATUS: ALGO INCOMUM. ")
    EscrevaL(" Você digitou os dados corretos? ")
 fimSe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `AND` e o `OR` é para fazer uma operação entre dois registradores, colocando o resultado em um outro registrador. Por exemplo:

```
and $a0, $a1, $a2
```

Isso coloca em `$a0`, o resultado de `$a1 AND $a2`.

Já o `ANDI` e o `ORI` é para fazer a operação entre um registrador e um número inteiro constante, também colocando o resultado em um outro registrados. Por exemplo:

```
andi $a0, $a1, 123
```

Isso coloca em `$a0`, o resultado de `$a1 AND 123`.

Para fazer o seu algoritmo, é melhor você reescrevê-lo assim:

```
inicio:
  se num1 <= 0 entao goto saida
  se num2 <= 0 entao goto saida
  x <- 10
  se num1 > x entao goto saida
  se num2 > x entao goto saida
  cont <- num1 + num2
  se cont = resultado entao goto parabens
  escreval("Você errou!")
  escreva("O resultado é: ")
  escreva(cont)
  goto fim
parabens:
  escreval("Parabéns você acertou!")
  goto fim
saida:
  EscrevaL(" STATUS: ALGO INCOMUM. ")
  EscrevaL(" Você digitou os dados corretos? ")
fim:
```

Essa forma é mais próxima ao que você vai traduzir em assembly mips. Use registradores para armazenar `num1`, `num2`, `x`, `cont` e `resultado`. Use também essas instruções nos blocos `se`:

- `BLEZ` - Salta condicionalmente para um label se o valor do registrador for menor que zero.
- `BEQ` - Salta condicionalmente para um label se o valor do registrador for igual a de um outro registrador.
- `BGT` - Salta condicionalmente para um label se o valor de um registrador for maior que de um outro registrador.
- `J` - Executa um saldo incondicional para um label.

O programa, exceto as partes de escrever textos, também usará `LI` e `ADD`.

Referência: http://www.di.ubi.pt/~desousa/2011-2012/LFC/mips.pdf

Comment: eu entendi perfeitamente sua lógica, mas estou tendo dificuldade para implementar essa mesma lógica usando números cujo o resultado gere um número com vírgula, tipo 5 / 2 = 2.5, compreende? e preciso trabalhar com esse tipo de número.

Comment: dividir:
 div $t0,$t1,$t2
 beq $t0, $t3, se
 j senao
se:
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, iguais
 syscall
 j encerra
senao:
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, diferentes
 syscall
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, resultado2
 syscall
 la $a0, ($t0) 
 li $v0, 1    
 syscall
 j encerra